# mysql equivalent of common table expression (CTE) in low version

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, common-table-expression, groupwise-maximum

I am trying to store a result-set of inner sub-query into a variable so that it is only calculated once.

Mysql version is `5.7.12`.

Here's my query:

```
select qs.*
from
(
    select
       tsk.id,
       tsk.request_id
    from
       user_tasks as usr 
       inner join
          unassigned_tasks as tsk 
          on usr.task_id = tsk.id 
    where
       usr.assigned_to = 53    
    AND 
        BINARY hash_id NOT IN ( SELECT hash_id  
                    FROM product_match_unmatches
                    WHERE request_id = tsk.request_id )
    ORDER BY tsk.id
) as qs

WHERE qs.id = ( SELECT min(qs.id) FROM 
(
    select
       tsk.id,
       tsk.request_id       
    from
       user_tasks as usr 
       inner join
          unassigned_tasks as tsk 
          on usr.task_id = tsk.id 
    where
       usr.assigned_to = 53    
    AND 
        BINARY hash_id NOT IN ( SELECT hash_id
                   FROM product_match_unmatches
                   WHERE request_id = tsk.request_id )
    ORDER BY tsk.id
) as qs
 WHERE qs.id > 83934 )
```

I have to run inner query `alias qs` repeatedly.

I tried referencing the alias `qs` later.

```
WHERE qs.id = ( SELECT min(qs.id) FROM qs WHERE qs.id > 83934 )
```

But `qs` doesn't exist error is displayed, which is obvious.

Is there any way equivalent to CTE to store the result-set into some variable?

Or any other way to optimize this query is welcome.

Comment: Is `unassigned_tasks.id` unique?

Comment: @stickybit no indexes added.

Comment: @Azima . . . You should ask a question about what you are trying to accomplish with the query -- with sample data and desired results.  Storing the result of a query in a variable is not "sensible" (you might want a temporary table).  But that is what you are asking.  There may be a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is this a "groupwise max" problem?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Answer (score 1):

There are no CTEs in MySQL prior to version 8. You'd have to repeat a subquery yourself, as you already did. One misconception though is, that a subquery is recalculated, when repeated. That's not necessarily right. So repeating it, while making it harder to read and change, isn't necessarily slower.

But, if I read this right and your intent is to limit the result to one row with the lowest ID, you could achieve that by using `ORDER` and `LIMIT` without any subquery at all.

```
SELECT tsk.id,
       tsk.request_id
       FROM user_tasks usr 
            INNER JOIN unassigned_tasks tsk 
                       ON usr.task_id = tsk.id 
       WHERE usr.assigned_to = 53
             AND tsk.id > 83934  
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM product_match_unmatches prmu
                                    WHERE prmu.hash_id = BINARY <tsk|usr>.hash_id
                                          prmu.request_id = tsk.request_id)
ORDER BY tsk.id
LIMIT 1;
```

I also changed the `NOT IN` to a `NOT EXISTS`, which could be faster, when `product_match_unmatches` contains a lot of rows. Unfortunately you didn't qualify `hash_id`, so I don't know whether it comes from `user_tasks` or `unassigned_tasks`. So you need to replace `<tsk|usr>` with the right alias.

Comment: `hash_id` comes from `product_match_unmatches` table itself.
and not from outer query

Comment: also you forgot the last `WHERE qs.id = ( SELECT min(qs.id) FROM qs WHERE qs.id > 83934 )`.
I tried to get the next row (after 83814) from the result-set.

Comment: @Azima: `hash_id` has to be (also) in one of `user_tasks` or `unassigned_tasks`, as it occurs outside of the subquery from `product_match_unmatches` in your code. You'd get an error if it wasn't in one of those tables. I edited the answer and added the `tsk.id > 83934` condition though.